# Troubleshooting Camera Page Display Issue in Multiple Browsers

Tags: azure, azure-devops, permissions, camera

I have developed a camera page using PHP and JS. The test code for the camera is attached below.

However, I am encountering an issue with displaying it in all browsers except Firefox (it works in firefox). Other browsers show an error regarding camera permissions, even though they have already been granted. The strange thing is that when the camera code is uploaded to another server, it works perfectly in all browsers.

However, when uploaded to our own server, the video and canvas elements do not display; it is just a blank white section. We are using an Azure cloud server for this. Could you please advise on what to check in order to make this camera page work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test code</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsqr/dist/jsQR.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Check for camera support
        if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            console.log('Camera not supported.');
        } else {
            // Access the camera and capture video stream
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                .then(function(stream) {
                    var video = document.getElementById('video');
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error accessing the camera:', error);
                });

            // Capture and decode QR code from video stream frames
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            function scanQRCode() {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var code = jsQR(imageData.data, imageData.width, imageData.height);

                if (code) {
                    console.log('Decoded QR Code:', code.data);
                }

                requestAnimationFrame(scanQRCode);
            }

            // Start scanning the QR code
            requestAnimationFrame(scanQRCode);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code? Are you sure this problem is related to Azure in any way? Would it work when hosting the page anywhere else?